# HELP - Need to restore the Event Content Type in SP 2013

Tags: content-type, site-column

Hoping someone can help...accidentally deleted the "Start Date" and "End Date" site columns and screwed up the Event Content Type.  Can it be restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to reactivate out-of-the-box Feature named `Standard Column Definitions`(ID: `CA7BD552-10B1-4563-85B9-5ED1D39C962A`) in order to provision missing site columns.

Since it is hidden feature, this operation should be performed via `PowerShell` or `stsadm`

Comment: Excellent suggestion Vadim.  Do you think restoring the standard columns would also restore the standard content types?

Comment: Thanks Mike, i hope it will help. Regarding restoring ootb content types, there is another feature named Standard Content Type Definitions(ID:695B6570-A48B-4A8E-8EA5-26EA7FC1D162) that could be reactivated also, in order to restore content types.